# Moodle Local plugin adding course administration menu item : Display Course administration Menu

Tags: moodle

I am creating a local plugin which adds a menu item to course administration.

I am able to add the new menu item, but on click of that link when the flow goes to a page ( in that local plugin ) , course administration is not available at the left.

How to display the course administration ( and make it open ) ?

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you may have to use the Navigation API and Page API to set the course administration menu in plugin page. Please refer:

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Page_API

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Navigation_API

Comment: thanks for replying. From page API, I set $PAGE->set_context to course context. One more thing is necessary. I set $PAGE->set_course to the course record. ie $courserecord = $DB->get_record('course', array('id' => $currCourseid), '*', MUST_EXIST); $PAGE->set_course($courserecord);

Comment: we can do require_login($courserecord); , then $PAGE->set_course($courserecord); is not needed

Comment: I studying Moodle for two weeks. Googling for stuff i can't find a way by myself i noticed Moodle developers never explain anything. They always like to link docs you already know. Funny.